# i use element insted of route becouse i use stripe for online payment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, stripe-payments

> Error: [Elements] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children
> of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

```
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

<Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripApikey)}>
  <Route
    path="/process/payment"
    element={
      <ProtectedR>
        <Payments />
      </ProtectedR>
    }
  />
</Elements>
```

I wrapped  all in route like that `<Route path="/process/payment" element={<ProtectedR ><Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripApikey)}><Payments /></Elements></ProtectedR>} />`  but after its gives error in my payment file × `Error: Could not find Elements context; You need to wrap the part of your app`

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite clear: within a `<Router>`, all direct children must be routes.

Move the `<Elements>` wrap inside `element={...}`.

```
<Route
  path="/process/payment"
  element={
    <ProtectedR>
      <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripApikey)}>
        <Payments />
      </Elements>
    </ProtectedR>
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

React Router, version 6

- Since [Elements] is not a `<Route>` component, it cannot be wrapped
  inside `<Route>`. That means Elements should be placed outside `<Route>`.
- All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or
  `<React.Fragment>`. Therefore, if there is a `<Route>` component, it
  must be wrapped around `<Routes>`.

The above statements result to the following syntax (in your case, there is a Protected Route):

```
<Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/process/payment" element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            <Route exact path="/process/payment" element={<Payments />} />
        </Route>
     </Routes>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

within `<Router>`, all direct children must be routes
and In your code you used `<Elements>`
as a direct child that's why It's showing error. So In `<Route />` use

```
 <ProtectedRoute>
```

to protect the `<Payment />` and wrap the

`<Payment />`

inside `<Elements></Elements>` as shown below.

```js
 {stripeApiKey && (
   <Route path='/process/payment' 
   element={
  <ProtectedRoute>
  <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}>
  <Payment />
  </Elements>
  </ProtectedRoute>
    } />
 )}
```

Comment: A answer with a detailed explanation is always better than just code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
      <Route
        exact
        path="/process/payment"
        element={
          stripeApiKey && (
            <ProtectedRoute redirectTo="/login">
              <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}>
                <Payment />
              </Elements>
            </ProtectedRoute>
          )
        }
      />
```